# Laravel queue worker freezes at 89MB memory usage

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, macos-catalina

## The problem

Recently I run into a problem where my Laravel queue worker freezes at 89MB. This happens consistently (it always freezes at 89MB memory usage) as I have asked my peers to run the same amount of jobs on their machines and also different versions of the code base.

## Some information around the code

### What the code does

We have created a command that creates a job entry for each of our records in a table. This creates about 10 000 jobs. Each job is tasked to take the information from the row and create a document in one of our Elasticsearch indices.

We have not made any recent changes to the code that produces our problem and we can confirm it was working about two months ago.

### What we have tried

1. Searched for the issue regarding Laravel, php, Elasticsearch and Macos Catalina (since we use macs and there was an update recently)
2. Used different minor versions of Elasticsearch 7.* and php 7.*
3. Ran 2 months old version of our code base.
4. Increase the memory_limit of php to 512MB (was 128MB).

*An interesting observation is that everytime the queue is stopped and then is started again the latest job fails with a max timeout exception*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: These kind of problems is not "mostly" related to how many jobs do you push but how many jobs do you consume in parallel. If you have 128 processes consuming the same queue then the limits of Elasticsearch will come into the game. The timeout is not related to memory problem, but more like the request to the third party services or databases.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tested both with a single queue worker and multiple ones. This used to work without any troubles until recently. We have not made any code changes or setup changes. The only thing else I can think of might be the new update that came out for the Mac OS, but I have not found any noteworthy issues on the internet with this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out with further testing that the issue was caused by the Xampp package (we believe it has something to do with the php that comes with).

I replaced the package with Ampps and everything works again correctly.